# MongoDB - Way to find closest results from arrays inside every document

Tags: mongodb

I want to find closest result from array inside document for every doc, and project it new object using MongoDB. It will be easier to explain what I trying to do by example:

Doc schema:

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "track" : [
    {
      "time": "number",
      "distance": "number"
    }
  ]
}
```

**EXAMPLE:**
I want to find closest results for every doc for time equals 4

**Input data:**

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "test1",
    "track" : [
      {
        "time": 0,
        "distance": 0
      },
      {
        "time": 1,
        "distance": 5
      },
      {
        "time": 3,
        "distance": 17
      },
      {
        "time": 4,
        "distance": 23
      },
      {
        "time": 6,
        "distance": 33
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "test2",
    "track" : [
      {
        "time": 0,
        "distance": 0
      },
      {
        "time": 1,
        "distance": 5
      },
      {
        "time": 2,
        "distance": 12
      },
      {
        "time": 4,
        "distance": 26
      },
      {
        "time": 6,
        "distance": 32
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "test3",
    "track" : [
      {
        "time": 0,
        "distance": 0
      },
      {
        "time": 1,
        "distance": 5
      },
      {
        "time": 3,
        "distance": 12
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Output data:**

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "result" : {
      "time": 4,
      "distance": 23
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "result" : {
      "time": 4,
      "distance": 26
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "result" : {
      "time": 3,
      "distance": 12
    }
  }
]
```

Is it possible to do this using MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "tracks": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$track",
          "as": "track",
          "cond": {
            "$lte": [
              "$$track.time",
              4
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "tracks": {
        "$slice": [
          "$tracks",
          -1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$tracks"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "tracks": 1,
      "name": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mzQ-SlfEaQV)

It does below things:

1. Finds whose track time is <=4 and adds it to an array called items
2. Then it gets the last element - i.e closer element
3. Take the element from array - unwind
4. Projects what is needed.

Comment: Glad. It helped.